# SQL Query to find missing numbers between 2 values

Tags: teradata

Need your expertise in writing an SQL for the below scenario

I have a  single row in a table "range_num"  as follows.

**start_num end_num**

**10          14**

Is there any way we can write a query to find all the gaps between 10 and 14 i ..e 11,12,13 in the below format

col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
10       11      12      13      14

I am using Teradata databases , so any compliant SQL query will be of great help!!

Comment: Does your range is fix ..means it will be 10 to 14.

Comment: No , it will vary in one row it is 10 and 14 , in another row it can be 3 to 7 ETC ..  Please help!

Comment: Say if you have range like 1-15 then you want to have 15 columns as well??

Comment: yes .. range can be from 1-15 or 0-13 or 3-11 , these are the possible scenarios and there will be multiple rows of them ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your problem...

```
    select 
max(case when   rownum=1 then gap end) as col1,max(case when   rownum=2 then gap end) as col2,
max(case when   rownum=3 then gap end) as col3,max(case when   rownum=4 then gap end) as col4,
max(case when   rownum=5 then gap end) as col5,max(case when   rownum=6 then gap end) as col6,
max(case when   rownum=7 then gap end) as col7,max(case when   rownum=8 then gap end) as col8,
max(case when   rownum=9 then gap end) as col9,max(case when   rownum=10 then gap end) as col10,
max(case when   rownum=11 then gap end) as col11,max(case when   rownum=12 then gap end) as col12,
max(case when   rownum=13 then gap end) as col13,max(case when   rownum=14 then gap end) as col14,
max(case when   rownum=15 then gap end) as col15,max(case when   rownum=16 then gap end) as col16,
max(case when   rownum=17 then gap end) as col17,max(case when   rownum=18 then gap end) as col18,
max(case when   rownum=19 then gap end) as col19,max(case when   rownum=20 then gap end) as col20,
max(case when   rownum=21 then gap end) as col21,max(case when   rownum=22 then gap end) as col22,
max(case when   rownum=23 then gap end) as col23
from
(
select a.id_start,
b.day_of_calendar as gap,
csum(1,1) as rownum
from db_sok.testt  a,
sys_calendar.calendar b
where b.day_of_calendar between a.id_start and a.id_end
)X
```

do a little tweaking in case you need something else...:)

Comment: tried to tweak but i was unsuccessful .. i only have 1 table , so was little confused on how to tweak it .. :(

Comment: give you table structure and in case you range is variable and its max list is not fix then you have to write an Stored Procedure to handle dynamic nature ...or wait for some expert to reply..:)

Comment: run this select end_num- start_num as gap 
from
 db_sok.testt order by  as gap desc as give me the max value..i will change the query accordingly if it is possible static one..else wait for some expert to pitch in..

Comment: The min and max value for start_num is 0 and 23 respectively , the min and max value for end_num us 0 and 23 respectively .. hope this helps..

Comment: run the edited one to solve your purpose temporarily but ofcourse it is not the best way and will hit performace in case you have too much data...